# mergedModelFromBundles in Swift not accepting optional argument

Tags: core-data, swift, migration, core-data-migration

I'm following Tim Roadley book tutorial on Core Data. I'm trying to do a Migration Manager in swift but I get this error: Extra argument 'forStoreMetadata' in call.
This is because this method is defined like this:

```
NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject],
forStoreMetadata: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

I think this is wrong because it is missing an option on bundles like this one is defined:

```
NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject]?)
```

How can I work this around? What I'm trying to do is:

```
var sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil, forStoreMetadata: sourceMetadata)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

In order to have the same behavior in swift as below:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *sourceModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil forStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
```

It is needed to declare [NSBundle.mainBundle()] instead of nil because it is not receiving an optional. This is the correct way because nil is also seen as the main bundle as you could see in NSBundle() documentation.

```
let sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()], forStoreMetadata: sourceMetadata)
```

I think this is an Apple bug because there is a lot of functions in swift which accept nil instead of NSBundle.mainBundle().

Answer (score 0):

The two class methods are defined as follows (Command-click on `NSManagedObjectModel` to jump to its header):

```
class func mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject], forStoreMetadata metadata: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> NSManagedObjectModel?
```

and:

```
class func mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject]?) -> NSManagedObjectModel!
```

Notice that `bundles` in this last one is declared as an optional, whereas in the first method it isn't. This means that when you pass `nil` to `mergedModelFromBundles`, the compiler is assuming you want the one that accepts `nil` and then complains that that method does not have a second parameter.

So, use the single parameter method if you are passing `nil`, or provide an actual `[AnyObject]` if you want to specify `metadata`.

**From Documentation**

> Sometimes a model—particularly one in a framework—may be used in
>   different situations, and you may want to specify different sets of
>   entities to be used in different situations. There might, for example,
>   be certain entities that should only be available if a user has
>   administrative privileges. To support this requirement, a model may
>   have more than one configuration. Each configuration is named, and has
>   an associated set of entities. The sets may overlap. You establish
>   configurations programmatically using **`setEntities:forConfiguration:`** or
>   using the **Xcode design tool**, and retrieve the entities for a given
>   configuration name using entitiesForConfiguration:.

and in:

```
class func mergedModelFromBundles(_ bundles: [AnyObject]!) -> NSManagedObjectModel!
```

`bundles` is:

> An array of instances of NSBundle to search. If you specify nil, then the main bundle is searched.

And for:

```
class func mergedModelFromBundles(bundles: [AnyObject], forStoreMetadata metadata: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> NSManagedObjectModel?
```

> Returns the managed object model used to create the store for the
>   specified metadata.  This method is a companion to the
>   `mergedModelFromBundles:` method;  in this case, the framework uses the
>   version information stored in the metadata for a store to locate the
>   models/entities used to create the store in the available bundles, and
>   return the model.  If the model for the store cannot be found, this
>   method will return nil.

Comment: But how can I pass nil to bundles and still add metadata?

Comment: I've added some more information to my answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've understood what you said but I still have the same question if I want to do something like this:
NSManagedObjectModel *sourceModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil forStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

In Swift it wouldn't be possible but in objective c it is.